# Reading a blob object (image) from google cloud storage is returning null in camel - spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am reading files from google cloud storage using apache camel in spring boot application. Content of files of type text/plain are returned successfully however image files returns nothing, and their content type returns null when printed.

java code (processor):

```
package processors;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Buckets;
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;




public class ListObjFromGCPProcessor implements Processor{

        public void process(Exchange xchg) throws Exception {
            
            //Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("D:/Users/User/MyFiles/Apache Camel github/SagesseMobileAppAPIs/camel-SagesseMobApp/src/main/resources/gcp-credentials.json"));
            Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
            
            
            Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list("sagessapp_test");
            String name = "kitten.png";
            
            for (Blob blob: blobs.getValues()) {
                if (name.equals(blob.getName())) {
                    byte[] content= blob.getContent();
                    xchg.getIn().setBody(content);
                    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(content));
                    System.out.println(blob.getContentType());
            
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    
}
```

gcp:
[image]
Any idea how to solve this issue and return the image content as base64?
Thank you

Comment: You mean that when you get a txt file the same code works but it doesn't work with you get a png file, correct? Are you sure that the file exist and the content is not null?

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere, yes it is the same code that is working for a txt file but not for a photo, the photo is uploaded on google storage, but you made me realize that it has 0B size, i will add a screenshot in the question. Thank you

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere actually I uploaded another photo, this time it did not return null but something like this: ```�j��m�ֽ�;U����xʤ����``` any idea how to return the image as base64. Thank you!!

Comment: You got a binary format. Encode it in base64.

Answer (score 0):

The file(kitten.png) appears on the image with 0-bytes size.
Once you validate that the file exists and the content is not null, you need to format it from binary to base64.